# how to resolve the plugin `cocoapods-acknowledgements`

Tags: swift, cocoapods

[!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-acknowledgements` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.

Answer (score 5):

Put this into the terminal

```
gem install cocoapods-acknowledgements
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-no-dev-schemes
```

It may help then you can reinstall your pods again

Or you can try this:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-repo-update
```

Then

```
$ pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) so you don't mess up the system Ruby environment. I needed to set `export OPENSSL_CFLAGS=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration` before I could run rbenv install  first. When you installed it run `rbenv local <ruby-version>`. Reload your shell (ie. `exec zsh -l`). Then run the `gem install cocoapods-acknowledgements`.